# Cambiar color de span dependiendo si esta vacio el input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$(function(){
  $('.contactanos :input')
.change(function(){
  var $input = $(this);
  var $span = $('.form__input-focus');
  if ($input.val() === '')
  {
    $input.css("background-color", "#fff");
    $(this).data("span").css("background-color", "transparent");
  }
  else
  {
    $input.css("background-color", "#000");
    $(this).data("span").css("background-color", "grey");
  }
});
});
```

```html
<style>
.form__input:focus+.form__input-focus {
background-color: #63E2FF
}
.form__input {
display: block;
border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
border-radius: 20px;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 9px 20px 7px;
line-height: 20px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
resize: vertical;
background-color: transparent;
background-size: 13px;
background-position: top 13px right 10px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-weight: 400;
color: #FFF;
transition: all .25s ease-in-out
}

.form__input:-moz-placeholder {
color: #FFF;
opacity: 1;
transition: all .25s ease-in-out
}

.form__input::-moz-placeholder {
color: #FFF;
opacity: 1;
transition: all .25s ease-in-out
}

.form__input:-ms-input-placeholder {
color: #FFF;
opacity: 1;
transition: all .25s ease-in-out
}

.form__input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #FFF;
opacity: 1;
transition: all .25s ease-in-out
}

.form__input:-webkit-autofill {
color: #000
}

.form__input:focus {
border: 2px solid #fff
}
.form__input {
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url(../images/select-tip.svg);
background-size: 13px;
background-position: top 15px right 16px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none
}
.form__input-focus {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: -40px;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border: 2px solid #63E2FF;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: trasparent;
transition: all .25s ease-in-out
}
</style>

<form class="contactanos" action="" onsubmit="return Submit()" id="form">
            <div class="form__group">
              <input data-span="span1" class="form__input" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Nombre Completo" required>
              <span id="span1" class="form-focus"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form__group">
              <input data-span="span2" class="form__input" type="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
              <span id="span2" class="form-focus"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form__group">
              <input data-span="span3" class="form__input" type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="Teléfono" required>
              <span id="span3" class="form-focus"></span>
            </div>
<div class="form__group">
              <textarea data-span="span4" class="form__input" id="body" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
              <span id="span4" class="form-focus"></span>
            </div>
          </form>
```

en la imagen el circulo a la izquierda es el span, al hacer clic en el input y escribir tiene efecto focus y se rellena de ese color, pero al quitar el clic y pasar a otro se desaparece. y lo que quiero saber es como hacer para que se quede relleno si esta escrito algo y si esta vacio quede como antes.

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Comment: No entendí nada en tu pregunta, deberías agregar mas información, por favor lee [ask], saludos.

Comment: modifique la pregunta, gracias por corregirme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes algun error, en el script `$` hace referencia a jQuery, no lo utilices para nombrar variables como si fuera php. Por otro lado, si utilizas `change` el color del relleno va a aparecer tras salir de un campo después de rellenarlo, mientras que el color de vacío solo aparecerá si se vacía un campo previamente rellenado, no aparecerá si no se rellena. Puedes probarlo en el ejemplo. Espero que te sirva

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").change(function(){
    var spid = $(this).data("span");
    if ($(this).val()=="") {
         $(this).css("background-color", "#dedede");
         $("#"+spid).css("background-color", "#dedede");
    } else {
         $(this).css("background-color", "red");
         $("#"+spid).css("background-color", "red");
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="contactanos" action="" onsubmit="return Submit()" id="form">
                <div class="form__group">
                  <input class="form__input" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Nombre Completo" data-span="s1" required>
                  <span class="form-focus" id="s1">span1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form__group">
                  <input class="form__input" type="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" data-span="s2" required>
                  <span class="form-focus" id="s2">span2</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form__group">
                  <input class="form__input" type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="Teléfono" data-span="s3" required>
                  <span class="form-focus" id="s3">span3</span>
                </div>
<div class="form__group">
                  
                </div></form>
```

Comment: Gracias Carmen por responder, aunque en realidad no era solo cambiar el color del input, quiero agregar color al span, que aca no se ve en el preview, pero si existe. ( pero podria definirlo como que deseo agregar color a cada span que acompaña a cada input, cada vez que tenga un texto el input que ese elemento "span" cambie de color, la broma es que si lo logro hacer, pero me cambia todos los span del formulario y no individualmente como el input lo hace. gracias. ) espero me entiendas jeje.

Comment: Tendrías que darle un id a cada span que lo relacione con el input, por ejemplo puedes darle a cada input un data-span con el valor del id del span y recoger ese valor del elemento data con $(this).data( "span"), de ese modo identificas el span correspondiente y varías el css

Comment: voy a intentarlo, a ver si lo logro. gracias. eres una pro. espero hacerlo.

Comment: quedaria asi: <input class="form__input" data-span:"span1" type="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                  <span id="span1" class="form-focus"></span>  y en js: $(document).ready(function(){
$("input").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()=="") {
         $(this).css("background-color", "#dedede");$(this).data("span");
    } else {
         $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }
});
}); quedaria asi? y como evalua el span1, span2, etc. para que sean independientes?

Comment: @Alexcertz se identifica por el id del span, que tiene el mismo valor que el data-span correspondiente. He editado la respuesta para que lo veas funcionando.

Comment: Gracias Carmen, me funciona genial adaptandolo a los input text, pero para los select option y textarea no me funciona y lo hice tal cual me explicaste.

Comment: <select class="selectpicker form__input" data-span="span4">
                    <option class="color" value="">Asunto</option>
                    <option class="color" value="1">obra</option>
                  </select>
                  <span id="span4" class="form__input-focus"></span>
<textarea data-span="span5" class="form__input" id="body" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
                  <span id="span5" class="form__input-focus"></span>

Comment: ya lo logre jeje, cambie el $("input").change(function(){ por, $(".form__input").change(function(){. colocandole la clase. gracias :3

Comment: @Alexcertz estupendo, veo que ya has encontrado cómo hacerlo. Me alegro de que te haya servido